# Is there a tool for analyzing the view hierarchy on the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, debugging, uiview

Looking for something like the webkit dev tools for analyzing web pages. Ideally it would show the view hierarchy textually, and moving your mouse over one of the views in that hierarchy would cause the actual view on the screen to become highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used it myself yet but [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect) looks quite nice. It lists "Print a views hierarchy to console" as one of its features.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Using it now and it's great. Very easy setup too. FYI, the version you linked to does not support ARC, but someone has forked it and created an ARC-compatible version here: https://github.com/jessedc/DCIntrospect/tree/arc

Comment: Ah cool. I should give it go too next time i fiddle around with uikit, looks very nice.